# Router to point to another ip

Tags: router, dns, routing, port-forwarding

I would like to know if it is possible, to let my router at home redirect to another ip. Eksampel: I have had a Minecraft server, but now it's on a new internet. So when people use old ip, it should just point to my new ip. Both routers have different ISP.

So if i enter 46.32.62.71 on Minecraft it should just point to spil.miningschool.dk - which is my domain set Up for the new server.

I have access to both routers.
The old ip router is a TP-LINK Archer AC1750
The new one is a NETGEAR something..

Comment: Short answer: NO. "Translating" public IP addresses into domain names is not and cannot be done by your home router.

Comment: Do you still have control over the router at the old address?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when people use old ip, it should just point to my new ip. Both
>   routers have different IPS

Assuming you mean both routers have different Internet Service Provider (ISP) and not IPS, this will mean they have a different internet connection to you and are on a separate LAN than you.

This means that **No you can't** just change your router to do what you want. This is because you cannot change the routers outside of your control, such as the general internet across 2 or more ISPs.

You would have to make changes to EVERYONE's routers who wants to connect, plus your own, some of which will not support, or have hard to find in the GUI, the static route feature required to perform this routing change. Plus you would need to change settings on your new server to accept traffic destined for the old address. Plus you would need to add special firewall rules on everyone's routers, everyone's windows, and possibly re-write minecraft, to allow return traffic to come from your new server's IP address instead of from the one minecraft thought it sent it to. Plus it would only be able to use IP addresses and not names anyway.

It would be **MUCH easier to make everyone switch over to using the name**, than reconfiguring everything for everyone.

Then in the future if you want to change servers you can just change the DNS registration to go to the new IP address. This is why the DNS system was invented.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I ment ISP - my phone autocorrected :)

Answer (score 1):

Routers cannot `NAT` an IP to a DNS name.  The two technologies are not connected.  It can, however, `NAT` one IP to another IP... but this largely depends on the router you have, and what it allows you to configure.  Keep in mind that any traffic going through your router would continue flowing through your router and your ISP.  You aren't "redirecting" a connection to another IP; you are acting as the middle-man.  If your IP changes, or if the router gets rebooted, all users would be kicked offline.

Comment: Basicly all i want to do, is when people type my old ip, then the server shows Up as online. From my tp-link Archer ac1750 (46.32.62.71) to the new ip 2.104.57.123

Comment: If I understood correctly, the OP has a new ISP (=> different IP address) and want redirection from the "old" to the "new", hence my comment above.